# Unknown error when using bcrypt.hash

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

I have this `pre` mongoose middleware for saving passwords,I previously used synchronous implementation,now I am doing an asynchronous implemntation as mongoose middleware:

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 5;

  if (!user.isModified('local.password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.local.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        user.local.password = hash;
        next();
    });
  });
});
```

The code just throws an unknown error when it gets to `bcrypt.hash` although the error is previously `null`. If I use something like `stackup`,the error looks like this:

```
E:\Do\login\node_modules\stackup\index.js:32
      error.stack = activeTrace.toString(error.stack);
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'stack' of No callback function w
as given.
    at AsyncListener.error (E:\Do\login\node_modules\stackup\index.js:32:19)
    at asyncCatcher (E:\Do\login\node_modules\stackup\node_modules\async-listene
r\glue.js:123:26)
    at process._asyncFatalException [as _fatalException] (E:\Do\login\node_modul
es\stackup\node_modules\async-listener\glue.js:211:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `bcrypt-nodejs`, which expects *two* callbacks:

```
hash(data, salt, progress, cb)
```

[docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs#api)

You've only provided it once, and so `cb` isn't defined when `bcrypt-nodejs` hits it.

Comment: The progress callback is optional, per the docs. If you pass `hash()` three arguments instead of four, it assumes you have omitted the progress callback. (I just tested it myself to confirm.) So I don't think that's the problem here. (It's what I immediately thought too, when I read the docs, though.)